# UIStoryboard segue fail

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I created a simple Show segue by dragging from a UIButton to another UIViewController in storyboard view. It's configured as all of my other VCs and has a custom class that is specified, with linked IBOutlets and IBActions (which appear to link up when I hover on them).

NOTE: When I first created it, there was no view controller class specified. I've recreated it several times since then, but I'm wondering if some value is cached that's pointing to a default view controller. Although I get print lines from the correct view did load method...

[image]

For some reason, when I run the app and click the button it links to a black, empty view controller. The navbar pops up without any back button (these views are embedded in UINavigationController).

After looking up other posts about this kind of issue, I've deleted and recreated the segue, cleaned my build folder and restarted Xcode. There's no source code involved in this, just storyboard configuration. **Any help on next steps?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code shown in your screen shot, the problem would be that NodeEnrollmentViewController is a subclass of UINavigationController. That's wrong. It should be a subclass of UIViewController.

You cannot (and do not need to) segue from a view controller *within* a navigation controller *to* a navigation controller.